# Asp.net present mysql database with json

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json

I am building a mobile application with xCode (swift). Swift cant access and read my database without a webservice to be an "intermediary".

I have found several tutorials on how to do this with .php, but since my webhotel is set up for .aspx, i really want to achieve the same with .aspx.

The following [link](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#connectiphonetomysql) explains how this is done with .php.

I'm having a hard time finding similar content for asp.net, so im wondering if this actually is possible? 
- Can this be done as simple as on the link ????

Comment: you can create web API project for this scenario--[check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! So that means i will be able to do it? 
- will there be any difference between php and .net? i mean a json object is a json object right?

Comment: All you would be doing is creating a API layer with .NET WebAPI project which internally talks to your database to retrieve data, the json data will be used in your mobile application, so there is no issues regarding the json object or json data just because you are using .NET over PHP, hope that helps good luck..!

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a shot :-)